# Ping started before backup uplink got installed still doesn't work, a new instance works

Tags: networking, router, ping

We have an internet outage, so our router got switched to the backup isp. I had a ping running continuously before the backup isp was enabled.

After the backup isp was enabled, the old ping still doesn't get any responses, but a new instance does?

I've verified the packets with tcpdump & wireshark: the ip addresses and ethernet addresses (destination and source) are exactly the same.

I'm assuming our funky cisco router is responsible for detecting these as separate flows (using the sequence numbers), and thus keeping the first ping out of service.

Is that how it's supposed to work? Shouldn't the router at least detect that the former route is no longer in service (the primary uplink cable is detached)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection / NAT state tracking: your ping is associated with a flow, and that flow has some state (nat-translated IP/port, allow/deny in the firewall etc).

As long as that flow exists, the router will not recalculate the state. A new ping causes a new session to start, which goes trough the NAT translation table as a new session etc...